# golang template with multiple structs

Tags: json, templates, go

I have struct that has JSON field something like this:

detail := &Detail{
 Name string
 Detail json.RawMessage
}

template looks like this:

detail = `At {{Name}} {{CreatedAt}} {{UpdatedAt}}`

My question can we use one or more structs for a single template or it is restricted to only one struct.

Comment: Detail is one struct, and it contains a Name string and json.RawMessage which is a bunch of bytes. Your template mentions CreatedAt and UpdatedAt. If your goal is to extract fields from the json.RawMessage and put them in the template, there are lots of ways to do that. Could you clarify your question?

Comment: yes I wanted to extract fields from json and add them in the same template. Also my question, is there a way we can work with multiple structs for one template?

Comment: AFAIK you can pass in only one "object" for your template, but that object could be, for instance, an array of structs of whatever type you want. HTH.

Comment: can you provide a valid playgroud snippet of what you want to do ?

Comment: I initially had multiple structs for a template, but I embedded these structs into a single struct this solved my problem

Answer (score 6):

You can pass as many things as you like. You haven't provided much of an example to work with, so I'm going to assume a few things, but here's how you would tackle it:

```
// Shorthand - useful!
type M map[string]interface

func SomeHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    detail := Detail{}
    // From a DB, or API response, etc.
    populateDetail(&detail)

    user := User{}
    populateUser(&user)

    // Get a session, set headers, etc.

    // Assuming tmpl is already a defined *template.Template
    tmpl.RenderTemplate(w, "index.tmpl", M{
        // We can pass as many things as we like
        "detail": detail,
        "profile": user,
        "status": "", // Just an example
    }
}
```

... and our template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    // Using "with"
    {{ with .detail }}
        {{ .Name }}
        {{ .CreatedAt }}
        {{ .UpdatedAt }}
    {{ end }}

    // ... or the fully-qualified way
    // User has fields "Name", "Email", "Address". We'll use just two.
    Hi there, {{ .profile.Name }}!
    Logged in as {{ .profile.Email }}
</body>
</html>
```

Hope that clarifies.