# Multiple Data Sending form Go file to Html

Tags: html, go

There are two struct:

```
    Offers   := "10% Discunt"
    SelectUsers := "ALL"
    OpenDate    := "29-06-2020"
    closedDate   := "29-07-2020"

}

type ScanInfo struct{
    IdScan    := "1212"
    Longitude := "98.323202"
    Latitude:= "34.432201"

}
```

Go method:

```
http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        
tmpl := template.Must(template.ParseFiles("home.html"))
        var scans []ScanInfo
        var infos []info

        tmpl.Execute(w, struct{ ScanData []ScanInfo }{scans})
    })
```

The method which I used to get Single types of data In html table is:

```
 <tbody>
    {{ range .ScanData }}
       <tr>
          <th>{{.IdScan}}</th>
          <th>{{.Longitude}}</th>
          <th>{{.Latitude}}</th>
        </tr>
      {{ end }}
 </tbody>
```

Now I want to send both of the struct's (**info  & ScanInfo's**) data into the HTML form (home.html) at a time.
Please Suggest's me anyways to send this data, and how can I get this values into the HTML page.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [golang template with multiple structs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25329647/golang-template-with-multiple-structs)

Comment: No. This is used for single struct. But I need to sent multiple struct at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easier to create a map for these cases instead of a struct:

```
 tmpl.Execute(w, map[string]interface{}{"ScanData":scans,"InfoData":infos})
```

In your template not you can use two top level variables, `{{.ScanData}}` and `{{.InfoData}}`